# How can I get the filename of the entry ".cake" file?

Tags: cakebuild

I'm trying to set up a consistent temp folder structure for a range of builds. Each build has its own folder and git-ignored "temp" subfolder. I'd like to have the path to the ".cake" file so I can use the relative ".\temp" folder.

I can get the directory to the executing Cake binaries (`Context.Environment.ApplicationRoot`) and I can get the working directory (`Context.Environment.WorkingDirectory`), but I can't see a way to get the path to the ".cake" file itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Context.GetCallerInfo()](https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Diagnostics/ScriptCallerAliases/D464584F) alias, it returns a [ScriptCallerInfo](https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Diagnostics/ScriptCallerInfo/) which contains a [SourceFilePath](https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Diagnostics/ScriptCallerInfo/AE3378F3) property.

Example usage:

```cs
var callerInfo = Context.GetCallerInfo();

Information(
    "{0}",
    callerInfo.SourceFilePath
);
```